# c# CUMULATIVE ADDWITHPARAMETER SQL

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a SQL string with a optional value...

If a combobox has a selecte value, the parameter will include a the  "AND NOMEEVENTO='blablabla'" part...

Else, the parameter will only add a space to the sentence.

But it's not working.

The only  help I get is

> Syntax error near @vOper

The code is:

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Connect);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM TBLANCAMENTO WHERE DATALCT >= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAINI , 103)  AND DATALCT <= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAFIM, 103) @vOper", conn);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vDATAINI", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vDATAFIM", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString());

            if (comboBox1.Text.ToString() != "")
            { 
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vOper", " AND NOMEEVENTO=" + comboBox1.Text.ToString());
            }

            else
            { 
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vOper", ""); 
            }
```

Comment: you do not need to convert a DTP value to string so that you convert it back to a date in SQL.  If @vOper is optional, you need to not have it in the SQL when they opt out.  And you should use `Add` not `AddWithValue`

Comment: I know that I don't need to convert DTP value to string... 
But the date DATALCT field is tricly as it recives their values from various sources that may, or may not, include hh:mm:ss data. 

To make sure that my string will return results just based on dd/mm/yyyy ignoring the time of the day, I did this conversion on both sides. I know that this is performance costly but that was a smaller problem for now.

Anyways, thanks for the observation, I will look for a improvement here.

Surely this is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have miss the single quote, reason for having a single quote is its string...

sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vOper", " AND NOMEEVENTO=' " + (ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text +' ");

Try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks,

Surely the ' ' is part of the solution, but i'm still get the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect Sintaxe near '@vOper'.

Comment: updated with (ComboboxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Connect))
using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    sc.Connection = conn;

    if (comboBox1.Text != "")
    {
        sc.CommandText = @"
            DELETE FROM TBLANCAMENTO
            WHERE DATALCT >= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAINI, 103)
              AND DATALCT <= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAFIM, 103)
              AND NOMEEVENTO = @vOper";

        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vOper", comboBox1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        sc.CommandText = @"
            DELETE FROM TBLANCAMENTO
            WHERE DATALCT >= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAINI, 103)
              AND DATALCT <= CONVERT(datetime, @vDATAFIM, 103)";
    }

    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vDATAINI", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vDATAFIM", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString());

    // other code
}
```